# Appending a char to a C-String

Tags: c, string

My following code works fine so far, but last time I tried to compile & execute it, it crashed for no reason. I tried to reproduce the error but it doesn't happen anymore after I tried it again and the code works.

Any clue why the program crashed just only one single time?

```
int main(void)
{
       char *aStr = "testing";
       char *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(sizeof(aStr)+1));
       strcpy(str, aStr);

       addChar(str, 's');
       printf("%s\n", str); //output should be "testings"
}

void addChar(char *str, char c)
{
     str = (char *) realloc(str, (sizeof(str)+2)*sizeof(char));
     str[sizeof(str)] = c;
     str[sizeof(str)+1]= '\0';
}
```

I know that's kind of a complicated way to do it but I wanted to know why it crashed.

EDIT:
    sizeof(str) should have been strlen(str)

Comment: No need to cast `void`-pointers in C.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is by definition 1, every size is in multiples of that of a `char`. That said, don't add various "edit" sections. Go in and fix that bug. However, take the time to extract a [mcve] from your code. The above isn't sufficient and if it is, you're not compiling with warnings turned on. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 6):

I see three main problems in your code, any of which may have caused a crash:

1. You're missing your `#include`s. In particular, `#include <stdlib.h>` is missing, which means `malloc` is undeclared. If `malloc` were declared, you wouldn't need those `(char *)` casts.

   In C89/C90 mode, C compilers just assume undeclared functions return `int`. On a 64-bit platform with 8 byte pointers and 4 byte `int`, this would cause calls to `malloc` to be miscompiled. In particular, this can corrupt the returned pointer (e.g. by truncating it to 32 bits), which can crash the program.
2. In `sizeof(aStr)` and `sizeof(str)` you're taking the size of a pointer (usually either 4 or 8 bytes), which is not related to the length of the string they're pointing into. You need to use `strlen` instead.

   On a 32-bit platform, you'd allocate just 5 bytes for an 8 byte string, which means `strcpy(str, aStr);` could crash (or corrupt memory enough for the next `realloc` to crash).
3. `str = realloc(str, ...)` in `addChar` is pointless. `str` is a local variable in the function; `str` in `main` still points at the old memory location. To make this work, you need to return the new pointer from `addChar` or make `addChar` take an output parameter (where it can store the result).

   If `realloc` is unable to resize the allocation in place, this will invalidate the old pointer, making it an indeterminate value. If it happens to overwrite the old memory with non-NUL bytes, this could make `printf` crash when it tries to output (what it assumes to be) the string.